# Samba network discovery fails through file managers, but works with smbtree

Tags: networking, samba, file-manager

In file managers (Caja, Nautilus, PCManFM, Dolphin), under *Network* there is an entry for *Windows Network* but double-clicking this brings up an empty window with 0 items.

However, `smbtree` does list the (Windows and linux) computer hosts online in the local network, their workgroups, and the directories and printers shared from them.

In a file manager, I can use the location address `smb://[HOST_IP]/[SHARE_DIRECTORY]` and it works. However, `smb://[HOST_IP]` without the directory gives an error:

> Error: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid argument. Please select another viewer and try again.

---

**EDIT:**
There are many similar bugs reported relating to samba configuration (which may still be the issue here). However newer bug reports suggest it may have to do with samba and Microsoft deprecating old protocols (SMB1): https://dev.solus-project.com/T1223 It is claimed that this newer issue is present on samba versions after 4.6.10.

Note that the computer with this issue is running Fedora 28 and samba 4.8.3. Another computer on the same network which can successfully browse shares is on Ubuntu 16.04 and samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu.

**EDIT:** It is not working on Fedora 36 and samba 4.16.8. Even `smbtree` no longer works, and prints the following message:

> main: This is utility doesn't work if netbios name resolution is not
> configured. If you are using SMB2 or SMB3, network browsing uses
> WSD/LLMNR, which is not yet supported by Samba. SMB1 is disabled by
> default on the latest Windows versions for security reasons. It is
> still possible to access the Samba resources directly via \name or
> \ip.address.

Answer (score 7):

#### Potential issue #1 - resolve order

Sounds like a resolving issue around NMB. It's mentioned here in this thread titled: [Nautilus doesn't see network computers... [SOLVED]](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=114648).

*non-discovering resolve order*

```
# What naming service and in what order should we use to resolve host names
# to IP addresses
name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
```

*reported to work resolve order*

```
name resolve order = bcast lmhosts host wins
```

Be sure to restart NMB/SMB services once you've made this change.

#### Potential issue #2 - client protocol

Researching your issue further, I came across this tip in this AU Q&A titled: [Nautilus fails to see shares in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031643/nautilus-fails-to-see-shares-in-18-04/1031706). The tip from there was to change the following:

```
$ more /etc/samba/smb.conf
workgroup = WORKGROUP
client max protocol = NT1
```

After making the above changes it's advised to reboot, not simply restart.

As part of this tip, make sure that avahi service is running:

```
$ sudo service avahi-daemon status
$ sudo service avahi-demon start
```

#### Potential issue #3 - firewalld

According to this askfedora.org article titled: [fedora 27 network browsing doesnt't work. Why?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/114231/fedora-27-network-browsing-doesntt-work-why/) it's suggested to try disabling firewalld. It may be inhibiting the ports 137-139 which are required for Samba's NMB/SMB services to function properly.

#### Potential issue #4 - Bug 1513394 with gvfs

Continued searches led to this issue that's still listed as open. The issue, titled: [Bug 1513394 - Applications using gvfs are unable to browse SMB shares](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1513394). It has to do with the package gvfs-smb.

> Applications using gvfs are unable to browse SMB shares

These steps can be used to see if the issue afflicts your system.

Steps to Reproduce:

```
1. nmblookup -M -- -
2. nmblookup -M workgroup
3. smbtree
4. gio list network://
5. gio list smb:///
6. gio list smb://workgroup
```

If things don't work the results from the steps above will look like this:

```
1. will return IP address for __MSBROWSE__ special name
2. will return IP address for workgroup master browser
3. will correctly list workgroup, workgroup members and their shares
4. returned items are missing workgroup members
5. will return empty
6. will return an error message "The specified location is not mounted"
```

If things are working the results will look like this:

```
1. OK
2. OK
3. OK
4. returned items should contain workgroup members
5. should contain workgroup name
6. should contain workgroup members
```

It should be noted that there doesn't appear to be a fix yet for this:

> For the record, it doesn't work in Fedora 28 and Samba 4.8 either.

Read the comments on the issue to see the rest of the story.

#### References

- [Nautilus doesn't see network computers... [SOLVED]](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=114648)
- [Problem viewing network on Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314598/problem-viewing-network-on-nautilus)
- [Ubuntu Sharing Issue](https://forums.majorgeeks.com/threads/ubuntu-sharing-issue.270346/)

Comment: As mentioned in the link in your comment, I have an entry in journalctl system logs about Kerberos: `gvfsd[2694]: Kerberos auth with '[USER]@[WORKGROUP]' (USER]\[WORKGROUP]) to access '[HOST_IP]' not possible`

Comment: Stopping firewalld with systemctl did not solve the issue.

Comment: @adatum - interesting, you want to try the kerberos solution to see if it fixes your issue?

Comment: What kerberos solution? I'm not familiar with kerberos but read it has to do with Active Directory domains, which I don't think I'm using (how can I check to be sure?).

Comment: @adatum - NM on the kerberos - walk through the docs to see if anything jumps out at you - https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/system-administrators-guide/servers/File_and_Print_Servers.html. Your issue lies w/ nmb service + potentially winbind. At this point I'd use `tcpdump` plus focus on the `nmb`'s logs.

Comment: My output for the "steps to reproduce" confirm the bug 1513394 with gvfs. This issue seems not to be exclusive to Fedora. The Solus bug that I linked to might be the same issue. I also previously tried live USBs of Ubuntu 18.04 and Manjaro 17.1.11 (without any samba configuration) and none could browse network shares. It's shocking that such basic functionality is so widely broken. So the answer is just to wait for a fix?

Comment: @adatum - that's one option, in that bug, they talk about putting things into SMB1 protocol instead of SMB2. Talked about here as well - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/. For Windows 10, apparently its disabled - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows. It can be reenabled per that URL.

Comment: Forcing use of SMB1 isn't viable in the long term or even safe given that it's being phased out for security reasons, so that's not really a solution. A temporary workaround at best.

Comment: @adatum - agreed - I wouldn't do that either. I'd just deal w/ the having to manually browse to shares until it gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now solved on Fedora 30 (MATE desktop environment) with Samba version 4.10.2 !

Places -> Network now shows Windows workgroups and connected computers. Browsing the shared directories works through the file manager. Everything seems as expected once again.

EDIT: It is not working any longer, at least on Fedora 36.

Comment: Not entirely. I have some machines that still is not showing up from fedora 30 / Nautilus while others are working fine. I would say that the fix is there for general use or for most usecases (including yours), but claiming this is permanently fixed sounds too loud or is simply subjective-fact-based.